# Python float number declaration

Tags: python, gpio

I'm stuck on this issue. This is my working code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO library
import time ## Import 'time' library. Allows us to use 'sleep'
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO Pin 7 to OUT
##Define a function named Blink()
def Blink(kartai):
    speed = 1
    for i in range(kartai):## Run loop numTimes
        print "Iteration " + str(i+1)## Print current loop
        GPIO.output(7,True)## Switch on pin 7
        time.sleep(speed)## Wait
        GPIO.output(7,False)## Switch off pin 7
        time.sleep(speed)## Wait
    speed = speed - 1/kartai
print "Done" ## When loop is complete, print "Done"
GPIO.cleanup()
kartai = raw_input("Enter length of each blink(seconds): ")
Blink(int(kartai))
```

However, with every iteration the LED blinks every second. I thought that happened because variable speed gets treated as an `int`, but if I rewrite the 7th line to:

```
float (speed) = 1
```

I get an error:

> can't assign to function call

in this line:

```
print "Iteration " + str(i+1)## Print current loop
```

Comment: try with `speed = 1.0`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading up on how [python assignments](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) work.

If you want `speed` to be a float, try `speed = 1.0` or `speed = float(1)`

Answer (score 1):

why not try with

```
speed = 1.0
```

that will assign a floating point number instead of an integer.

And of course (as answered already), you can still cast the integer to a float doing

```
speed = float(1)
```